# network drive - access denied - second login required

Tags: windows-7, networking, hard-drive, permissions, samba

Windows 7 says "Access denied" when trying to open a mapped network drive. The permissions are setup correctly. **When you logout and login again (don't reboot), it's possible to access the drive.** I thought this is caused by a windows service started at boot time, but I've uninstalled / disabled all services that don't belong to windows and it didn't change anything.

The server is samba. It's only one drive affected. It's one user account and one machine only. There are no error messages in event log.

Comment: Are you trying to login from another Windows 7? This issue is possibly caused after an update, KB4480970/KB4480960.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the proper credentials are stored in the credential manager. Try deleting associated Windows credentials and then adding them again.

Comment: I'll try this, but it's the Windows username / password entered when logging in. The other shares use the same authentication.

Comment: If they're not in the same workgroup or domain you may have to prepend the username with either the domain name or the computer name.

Comment: Also make sure you're not running samba with "security = share".

Comment: There are no credentials stored, because the Windows login password is used. It's a domain share like the other shares which are working! It is the same domain. Samba is configured as domain controller.